# Limiting length of string to paste to textarea

Tags: php, textarea

I need to paste the output of a python script to a textarea. However as the output is a return from a log search it can be rather long.

If it gets too long I get the *Warning: Unknown: POST Content-Length of 8499553 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes* error.
So I tried to write it to the textarea only if it shorter than 8000000 but somehow my if clause doesn't seem to catch:

```
exec("python ../syslog_webUI/build_search_function.py $parameters", $return);
    if (strlen(reset($return)) < 8000000) {
        $vals = $return;
    } else {
        $vals[] = "Output too long!";
    }
```

$vals is imploded to the texarea.

Any ideas why the too long return isn't caught?

Comment: Because you are only checking the length of the first element of `$return`?

Comment: Only one element is returned. I tried to assign the first element of the array to a string variable and use that as an input to the textarea but I run into the same problem with the size and the limiting if clause not catching.

Comment: _"Only one element is returned."_ - you mean, the content of `$return` is just one single item? And if so, is that an assumption, or did you actually verify that?

Comment: The python script returns a list but that list is the first element of the php array. When I echo sizeof($return) it's alway 1.

Comment: But you are adding _everything_ this array might contain to `$vals`, and you say you were imploding that later.

Comment: I changed it to if (strlen(reset($return)) < 8000000) {$val = reset($return);} and fill the textarea with $val but the size problem remains.

Comment: Okay, I moved <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> to below the PHP section and now I get the proper output if the size is too big. But now some parts of the css go wonky :-D